# Is it legal for everyone to register .me domain?

Tags: domains, registration

Can anyone register a `.me` domain name?

Can it used for commercial uses?

Answer (score 1):

There is no restrictions for registering a `.me` domain, it's open to anyone like for `.com`, `.net` etc. You can register a `.me` domain for business, especially if you target Montenegro local business (the `.me` extension is assigned to Montenegro as a country code).

Comment: Thats exactly why I am asking this question, can I still use it if it has no relation to Montengro?

Comment: No problem because there is no restrictions, you can use it as well even if you start a business in the USA.